# How can I make a caption visible in a relationship line in erd MySQL WB 6.0

Tags: mysql-workbench, erd

I've tried putting a content in the caption but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 8):

Edit > Preferences > Diagram > Unhide Caption ;)